# how to get the username value from url in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

i want get the username from URL i attach the pic when button click URL is change i want to get username value in variable. Kindly help me

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
    <tr>
        <th>
            User
        </th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (User item in Model.user_get)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UserName)
                <input type="button" value="Add User" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action($"Create/username={item.UserName}", "addgroupmember")'" />
                 
            </td>


        </tr>
    }

</table>


   

            public ActionResult Create()
            {
                dynamic dy = new ExpandoObject();

                dy.user_get = get_user();

                Uri MyUrl = Request.Url;
                Console.WriteLine(MyUrl);
                string name = Request.QueryString["username"];



                List<string> selectedUsers = new List<string>();
                selectedUsers.Add(name);
                return View(dy);
        }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b9vEb.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
var qsArray = Request.QueryString.AllKeys.Select(key => new { Name = key.ToString(), Value = Request.QueryString[key.ToString()] }).Where(a => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(a.Value)).ToArray();
var UserName= qsArray.Where(a => a.Name == "username").Select(a => a.Value).ElementAt(0);
```